# Can a droplet of formalin evaporate in midair while falling?

Tags: thermodynamics, vapor-pressure

I am designing an evaporator for use in an enclosed environment. Due to the hazardous nature of formaldehyde, I want my evaporator to be wick-free.
The environment in which the evaporator will be used is at a pressure of -10Pa to the outside atmosphere, has a humidity of 32%RH and a temperature that sits at around $36.5~ ^\circ \rm C$.

The basic design for my evaporator is a long tube with an induction coil wrapped around its length and an opening at the bottom for the vapour to escape. As the droplet makes it way down through the heated tube I am hoping that with enough heat it will vaporise and be mixed into the enclosed atmosphere.

The solution I am using is formalin 40.
http://www.strathclydenutrition.com/index.php/Page/product_page/formalin-401
The room in which the vapour is required has a large fan that circulates the air, though I don’t know what speed this runs at or if this will effect the air in my evaporator tube.

I have yet to develop a prototype of my design and short of gaining a thermodynamics or chemical engineering degree, I thought I’d ask the friendly folks at the Physics Stack Exchange if you could help me first.
Any links to external tutorials or articles would be greatly appreciated.